# MVC 5 asp.net want to encrypt the database connection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, encryption, asp.net-mvc-5

as you know, the database connection parameters are listed in **Web.Config** which it's **text**, now the app is hosted in Windows, I want to apply follwoing:

```
1- exe file by clicking it should ask for the following
     a -> database server host address
     b -> database server sql user name
     c -> database server sql database
     d -> database server sql user password
```

after all the parameters are correct it should allow to store the connection and I will address the connection in webconfig(connection file) is for sure encrypted and it's show only encrypt the server detail(iis server) which even if some one copy the app folder to another server it should not work

--> here I know how to encrypt only in single file but the problem is for developing such exe which should check the detail connection if it's success and by server-IIS detail

where I should start, help of experts saves our time , best wishes

I went trough this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921936/asp-net-mvc-4-how-should-i-encrypt-the-connection-string-to-my-production-sql) but could not solve.

Comment: @Valkyriee any idea ..

Comment: [This is the solution for your issue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx)

Comment: but this is both side, encrypt and decrypt thing I need is custom which if I encrypt no one should be able to decrypt it

Comment: Try [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx) even though it is bit complicated.

Comment: not much different, it's not what i am required to thank you

Comment: I am also new to this. But it is quite interesting. Read [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/795135/Encrypt-ConnectionString-in-Web-Config) code project article. Once you encrypt, you only can decrypt it. In another system it will throw an error. This is the thing you're looking for.  @hamza

Comment: thanks, @ViVi but the thing is it's not me who should encrypt i need a exe file which open form and there i should submit detail for user,pass,database,host for the MSSQL and once i sumbit it should generate , file.txt and with encrypted data and i will include file.txt in web.config it's get's connect this how is in place where i work, but i need to develop it my self for my project

Comment: Are you planning to create a new windows application just for encrypting this? But what is the use? @hamza

Comment: yes, as develop application and publish for deploy, the administrator will receive the deploy patch and will only change the connection by the user and password and host and database he will receive from the database administrator so now the application connection string information will be only with application administrator as database administrator will provide read or write only user for application administrator, that why i need to develop windows form created dbconn.txt and include in webconfig for app and db conneciton

Comment: It is possible to create such an application if you really wish to. Run cmd arguments from c# and get the encrypted key and using stream writer, write the web.config file or the connection string file.

Comment: yes that is possible currently we have application using it, but as it's commercial they will not provide the method they have used, so i want to try it my own but don't know where to start

Comment: Get an idea on how encryption is done using command prompt in above situations. You can execute command line arguments in c# easily. Run the required arguments, get the text and using stream writer start writing the config file. It might take some time though.

Comment: yes that right, now i am trying to develop simple C# connection form and checking then i will go for encryption and then i will try it in web.config

Comment: @ViVi https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJtYocdza1U